# Auto complete example is not working

Tags: google-caja

I'm trying to run `http://caja.appspot.com/?es5=false#examples/jquery-autocomplete.html`.
When I type something in the text box, I see an error in console:

```
Domado: HTMLLIElement is not tamed; its specific properties/methods will not be available on < li >.
```

I tried on Mac-Chrome

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure is it about that but u can try at Autodetect Mode

http://caja.appspot.com/?es5=auto#examples/jquery-autocomplete.html

Comment: Am trying to run in Google app script and its not working there. So tried the example here.